# Evento click não funcionando

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Notícia</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
    <a class="noticia" data-noticia="6" href="#">Funciona</a>
    <br>
    <a class="noticia" data-noticia="5" href="#">Funciona</a>
    <br>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            var listaNoticias = [{
                    Id: 4,
                    Titulo: 'Testando detalhes',
                    Autor: 'José Mario',
                    Data: '10/10/2010'
                }, {
                    Id: 3,
                    Titulo: 'Testes testes',
                    Autor: 'Riv Scart',
                    Data: '10/10/2010'
                }, {
                    Id: 2,
                    Titulo: 'Testando testes',
                    Autor: 'Joab Costa',
                    Data: '10/10/2010'
                }, {
                    Id: 1,
                    Titulo: 'Testando detalhes',
                    Autor: 'Thiago Silva',
                    Data: '10/10/2010'
                }];
            var itens = "";
            $.each(listaNoticias, function (i, item) {
                itens += "<a class ='noticia' data-noticia='" + item.Id + "'  href='#'>" + item.Titulo + "</a><br>";
            });
            $('body').append(itens);
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".noticia").click(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('data-noticia');
                localStorage.setItem('id', id);
                alert(localStorage.getItem('id'));
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

O problema é o seguinte: no momento que eu adiciono o conteúdo de listaNoticias no html, os itens adicionados não funcionam no evento $(".noticia").click(), contudo os 2 itens que já foram inseridos funcionam (data-noticia 5 e 6). O que pode ser?

Comment: Para itens dinâmicos você precisa usar o ON, no seu caso ficaria `$(document).on('click', '.noticia', function(e) {e.preventDefault;//Continuação})`

Comment: Problema resolvido. Obrigado!

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar uma das respostas como correta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

para funcionar você deve substituir o trecho abaixo:

```
$(".noticia").click(function(){
```

por:

```
$(document).on("click", ".noticia", function(){
```

Como os seus elementos não estão presente no DOM quando a página é carregada o evento click não foi 'adicionado' para eles. fazendo a substituição sugerida, mesmo que o elemento não esteja no DOM quando foi carregado o click será disparado.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você carrega itens novos `dinamicamente`, o correto seria a utilização do evento `ON` do JQuery.

No seu caso ficaria:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.noticia', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault; //Não executa a ação padrão
        //Continuação
    });
});
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado.